# mongoose query $in with case insensitive regex not working

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an email column in mongoDB where I have to check the fields in array, currently I am using following query

```
emailArray = [
  { '$regex': /test@email.com/i },
  { '$regex': /test2@email.com/i },
 ]
'$or': [ { email: emailArray }, { name: 'testUser' } ] }
```

I am getting following error

> Cast to string failed for value "[object Object]" at path "email

I am not sure what is wrong with the query :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `emailArray` should be array of regex also you are missing the `$in` in the query.

```
var emailArray = [ /test@email.com/i, /test2@email.com/i ]
db.collection.find({ 
    '$or': [ 
        { 'email': { '$in': emailArray } }, 
        { 'name': 'testUser' } 
    ] 
})
```

Comment: that saved my issue, thanks again for saving my time :)